# How to enable Bitcode for WebRTC iOS framework?

Tags: ios, webrtc, bitcode

How can I compile WebRTC iOS framework with Bitcode enabled. Currently I have to disable the Bitcode of my project due to WebRTC framework.

Answer (score 13):

You will need to build it yourself.
Something like:

```bash
# Clone the depot tools
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
# Add the tools to the path
export PATH=$PATH:"`pwd`/depot_tools"
# Download the WebRTC source code
mkdir webrtc_ios
cd webrtc_ios
# This will take some time
fetch --nohooks webrtc_ios
gclient sync
# Let's start building
cd src
# Build the framework, remove --arch "arm64 x64" to build ALL architectures, including 32 bit
tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py --bitcode --arch arm64 x64
# The framework is at out_ios_libs/WebRTC.framework
```

Documentation: https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/

**Update:**
Starting with Xcode 14, bitcode is no longer required ([see release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes)), and no longer supported in submissions.
The google WebRTC neglected to fix an ARM build issue with bitcode for so long, they just waited it out...
the `--bitcode` option is no longer supported by the build script.
To continue building using my instructions, remove it:
`tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py --arch arm64 x64`

Comment: it fails on fetch --nohooks webrtc_ios

Comment: @NasirKhan Fetch works fine, however, it seems that the last command had changed a bit. I updated it to match the new behavior.

Comment: it says: Could not find gn executable at: .../webrtc_ios/src/buildtools/mac/gn

Comment: @NasirKhan All I can tell you is to make sure you copy pasted everything correctly, did the whole process yesterday (latest Xcode, latest macOS, latest command line build tools) and it worked just fine.

Comment: i have created a folder, in that folder i run these all commands, just let me know is this how it would work?

Comment: Thanks! This works great, although the build for all architectures is huge (over 1GB). What would be the best way to include it in production? (btw. after stripping the bitcode it's 22MB)

Comment: @bojan In production, the actual binary downloaded to devices does not include bitcode, the user only downloads sliced and stripped code, so that shouldn't be a problem. Takes a bit longer to upload to the iTunes Store though :-(

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Thanks! I already read about it:) Plus I actually found a build script to remove unused architectures from the library. The issue now is, what would be the best way to keep it in the project between team members, as the building takes forever.

Comment: @bojan Building takes forever, it's true, I'd keep `--arch arm64 x64` to make sure it only builds for these architectures (and then you don't need to strip it), as for sharing this file - I have a bootstrap script that either copies it from a file server or, builds it, based on it's parameters. Even copying it from a fileserver takes a bit :-)

Comment: @MosheGottlieb "I have a bootstrap script that either copies it from a file server or, builds it, based on it's parameters" good idea! Thanks again! Just one more question do you find the library reliable in production? :)

Comment: @bojan So far, it works fine for me, so yes, I find it reliable. The thing is, I still don't know how to checkout a specific version, and my script pulls the latest, so it's hard to stick to a known and trusted version, unless you save a working copy on your server, like I do.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb thank you a lot, a build follow your instruction but get error in the last step, can you help me to resolve this: "../../stats/rtc_stats.cc:30:17: error: loop variable 'element' is always a copy because the range of type 'const std::vector<bool>' does not return a reference [-Werror,-Wrange-loop-analysis]"

Comment: @goat_herd Unfortunately, this is an issue with the latest clang that comes with Xcode and that specific file, we'll need to wait for google to fix this, or append `use_xcode_clang=false` to the build script, but that will mean we'll use google's specific clang version which does not support bitcode, so there's not much sense doing that.

Comment: Anyone facing this `clang++: error: -mllvm is not supported with -fembed-bitcode` while running `tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py --bitcode --arch arm64 x64`?

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy Yes. Im facing the same issue too

Comment: @SampathD These links might help - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648366/bitcode-enable-for-ios-webrtc-framework-error-mllvm-is-not-supported-with-fe), [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=13440#c4).

Answer (score 6):

according to the official doc, you have to compile manually. More details there:

- main page: https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/
- iOS page: https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

bottom of the page (last paragraph) includes instructions to build with bitcode support:

To build the framework with bitcode support, pass the --bitcode flag to the script like so

**python build_ios_libs.py --bitcode**

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/main/docs/native-code/ios/index.md updated link. The last paragraph still points to bitcode issue.

Comment: This solution doesn't work - it leads to an error