# How to build webRTC Framework for ios

Tags: ios, webrtc

I want to build the WebRTC framework. but I have some problems.

Google provides guide about this.
https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/

here is my code

```
# debug build for simulator
gn gen out/ios_sim --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="x64"'
```

but it failed with the following comment.

```
ERROR at //webrtc.gni:486:32: Assignment had no effect.
        xctest_module_target = "//base/test:google_test_runner"
                               ^-------------------------------
You set the variable "xctest_module_target" here and it was unused before it went
out of scope.
See //testing/test.gni:451:5: whence it was called.
    target(ios_test_target_type, _test_target) {
    ^-------------------------------------------
See //webrtc.gni:443:3: whence it was called.
  test(target_name) {
  ^------------------
See //BUILD.gn:536:3: whence it was called.
  rtc_test("rtc_unittests") {
  ^--------------------------
```

I can't find any information about this error.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Spent close to 2 days on this, nothing but dead ends. You follow the instructions to the letter, and it fails. This in unreal. Been searching for hours and found NOTHING. Only thing is a python script that actually works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55125861

Answer (score 8):

Late response, but for those still struggling with this issue - I had the same problem, and solved by building with 'rtc_include_tests=false', i.e:

```
gn gen out/ios_sim --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="x64" rtc_include_tests=false'
```

Answer (score 0):

Garth answer solves the problem, but as I understand, it removes tests. I found solution for solving this problem without this side effect. You need to add `enable_run_ios_unittests_with_xctest=true` flag to the args.

```
gn gen out/ios --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64" enable_run_ios_unittests_with_xctest=true'
```